# Error regarding DNS - "... must be able to resolve names ..." (Windows Server 2008 R2 installation)

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I'm trying to replace our old Windows 2000 Server by a Windows Server 2008 R2. I followed [the guide at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731188%28WS.10%29.aspx). Coming to the step "[Install Active Directory Domain Services...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755103%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)" the option to install the DNS-Server was grayed-out. According to [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002584/en-us) I skipped the DNS Server Installation at this point. (Because of the **single-label DNS name**)

I then installed the DNS-Server role and created a forward-lookup-zone for the domain. When running the Best Practices Analyzer of the DNS-Server role I get these two messages for both domain controllers (the old win2k and the new win 2008 R2):

- [The DNS server [IP address] on [adapter name] must be able to resolve names in the primary DNS domain zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378829%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [The DNS server [IP address] on [adapter name] must be able to resolve names in the forest root domain name zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391921%28WS.10%29.aspx)

The TechCenter articles suggest to use a proper DNS Server - that's pointless when I try to configure a proper DNS Server.

How do I configure the DNS Server in a way that it resolves these zones?
Or are these errors irrelevant?

> dcdiag /v /test:DNS

Seems to run fine...

Answer (score 1):

dcdiag /test:dns options tests some of the records relevant for DCs. It doesn't test all of them. However, if that works, thats a good start.

I dont know why you created a forward lookup zone for the domain. What type of zone storage were you using in Windows 2000? I would have expected that zone to replicate when you promoted the new DC.

If you can resolve records in the zone using tools like nslookup pointed against the Windows 2008 R2 DNS server, I would ignore this. However, feedback on the BPA functionality is welcomed as per http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2009/02/11/best-practices-analyzer-resolution-guidance-now-available-online.aspx

You could feedback to support engineers that monitor the official AD support blog at http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/08/02/new-dns-and-ad-ds-bpa-s-released-or-the-most-accurate-list-of-dns-recommendations-you-will-ever-find-from-microsoft.aspx or at http://connect.microsoft.com/ADBPA .

Comment: I have no idea what storage was used on 2k. The whole update thing was a bit tricky because of the single label DNS name. It's a bad idea to use these, but we didn't want to change it...

After running for one year there were no issues regarding DNS, so maybe that's really neglectable. Maybe I'll investigate that further and give some feedback to BPA.